# Cannot subsript a value of type anyobject in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I am migrating to swift 2.0 I was using following code well. But I am getting errors in swift 2.

```
        SRWebClient.POST("upload url")
            .data(imageData, fieldName:"image_field", data: ["username":"username","key":"test"])
            .send({(response:AnyObject!, status:Int) -> Void in
                if status == 200 {
                    var s_status=response?["status"] as! Int
...
```

I am getting following error for `var s_status` line.

```
Cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyObject!' with an index of type 'String'
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that you can't use ["status"] on an object of type AnyObject, because it may not work if it's not a dictionary.  You need to convert response to a Dictionary first.

I see you're using SRWebClient, which I've never used, but according to their github this seems safe:

```
let responseJSON = response! as Dictionary<String, String>
```

I'm guessing they serialize in their code first.  I dunno though... I'd make sure that object was a Dictionary before forcing a cast.

Comment: I have one more problem like this. Do you know how to resolve this? http://prntscr.com/8khotd

Comment: Yeah it's the same problem.  When you pull an item out of an NSArray in swift, it's an AnyObject.  You'll need to cast it.  Here's an example if you think the retrieved object is an NSDictionary.

`for item in data {`
`if let itemDict:NSDictionary = item as? NSDictionary {`
`let username = itemDict["username"]`
`}`
`}`

Sorry, it's not letting me put my code on separate lines.