# Cannot subscript a value of type nsobject anyobject with an index of type String

Tags: swift2

I want to get name from google places using address dictionary in my xcode 7 project 
Here is my code :

```
let name = placemark.addressDictionary["Name"] as? String
let city = placemark.addressDictionary["City"] as? String
let state = placemark.addressDictionary["State"] as? String
```

Comment: May be this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791232/cannot-subsript-a-value-of-type-anyobject-in-swift-2

Answer (score 0):

In otherwords NSObject and AnyObject are not subscript able with a string.

It's not the clearest message. 
You might try NSString subscripts or you might not be able to use subscript syntax without more type info to tell Mr. compiler that your objects can respond to subscript syntax